# Are there any cheap/discount/budget flights from Yerevan, Armenia to Moscow, Russia?

Tags: air-travel, budget, armenia, yerevan, moscow

A fellow guest at my hostel here in Batumi is planning to travel to Armenia and then wants to fly from the capital Yerevan to Moscow, Russia.

But the flights she can find are not so cheap compared to other destinations in this part of the world. The cheapest one way flight she can find is about 270 euros including taxes.

**So are there budget flights between these destinations in nearby countries with a friendly relationship between each other that we're just missing due to not knowing the good websites in Russian or Armenian?**

**Or is this just an inherently expensive route?**

Comment: I would venture a guess that it would be an inherently expensive route given how isolated Armenia actually is now.

Comment: do you have dates for this flight, or just 'any time'?

Comment: And which airline was the 170 Euros with?  I'm working on it

Comment: @MarkMayo: Kinda soon, but I didn't want to ask a "too localized" question so I kept it general. She's asleep right now but I'll ask her who she got the 170 quote from.

Comment: In fact I messed it up - her best quote was 270 euros so you definitely beat it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numerous carriers fly to Yerevan:

Armavia, AirFrance, Lufthansa, Iran Air, Czech Airlines, Austrian Airlines, Aeroflot and the like. Yerevan is connected to all major European and Middle Eastern cities: London, Paris, Amsterdam, Athens, Moscow, Vienna, Berlin, Prague, St Petersburg, Zurich, Minsk, Riga, Kiev, Istanbul, Dubai, Aleppo, Tehran, Beirut and so on. Air Arabia connects Yerevan to the Gulf states, Egypt and India via Sharjah. Armavia reopened the Route Yerevan - Tbilisi - Yerevan again, with two daily flights last year.

I also checked my trusty S7 Airlines (the English link is at the top left of their page), and confirmed that they can get you there for 197 Euros, pretty much any time of the year.

Even using ITASoftware, the best I can see is 193-196 Euros any time in July (arbitrarily picked month), same for November, same for February, and ... oh...

Now we're getting somewhere, I assumed it might be cheaper later on, but it's actually cheaper this month.  Still the best I can see is on May 30th for 189 Euros, with Aerosvit, stopping off in Kiev.  That's on a search that includes Aeroflot, Aerosvit, S7 Airlines, Austrian Airlines, Transaero, Lufthansa, British Airways, BMI and many many more, as well as combinations of the above into 'hacker fares'.

So long story short, for now (I may play more later), it just looks like that's the price - around 170 (you found) to 190 Euros, depending on the airline of your choice and route you take.

**stats**

Farecompare has some 'facts' about this route:

- Kuban has 5 one stop flights between Yerevan, AM and Moscow, RU.
- The shortest flight between Yerevan, AM and Moscow, RU on BMI is 3,834 miles.
- 24 flights per week fly out of Yerevan, AM connecting to Moscow, RU
- Paris, FR is the most popular connection for one stop flights between Yerevan, AM and Moscow, RU.
- The smallest aircraft operated by Lufthansa flying between Yerevan, AM and Moscow, RU is a 737 with 126 seats.
- 15 airlines operate between Yerevan, AM and Moscow, RU
- Armavia has the most nonstop flights between Yerevan, AM and Moscow, RU.
- 24,471 seats are available per day to fly out of Yerevan, AM connecting to Moscow, RU

Comment: Wow what a complete answer! And bonus kudos for the interesting factoids too (-:

Comment: Well I figured some of those factoids could help with flight searching - the number of airlines, popular connection etc.  :)

Comment: Note that depending on your nationality, there might be visa issues when you choose a non direct flight.